# Samba printers installation

Tags: windows, samba, installation, cups

Is there any open source software which allows to install on the windows clients samba/cups printers from the web based interface? Something like Novell iPrint

Comment: CUPS has a built-in web interface. Does this not do what you want?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question, I meant installation on the Windows clients not adding printer to CUPS server.

Comment: I am looking for a software where I can see the list of all printers from SAMBA/CUPS on the web page and after selecting one of them, printer driver will be installed on windows client.

Answer (score 0):

In the past what I've done is make use of Samba to distribute drivers for different versions of print drivers. I wrote about this in a blog article.

- [Howto Install Windows Print Drivers onto a Central Samba Share](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/2118/howto-install-windows-print-drivers-onto-a-central-samba-share/#more-2118)

The key concept is to setup a `print$` share on the Samba server and then make use of the `Advanced` tab under the properties of a network installed printer. This would be a system that already has this printer setup.

[image: ss of windows printer advanced tab]

Once the drivers have been installed they're show up automatically to any clients that make use of this CUPS printer.